# iText PDF template dynamic row insertion on tables

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I have a requirement where I need to generate a PDF document in Java using iText.
The ask is to use a PDF template, and inject the data values in a user designed PDF template to produce the desired output PDF.

The documentation on the iText site is not clear/or I didnt search them completely, so asking for support or article regarding this,
Our use case is to generate a table from a PDF template, where the number of rows is determined by the data (i.e. in here JSON). I should be able to dynamically scale the number of rows in a PDF template based on the data size.
Is this possible?
I was referring to this article:
https://github.com/koendehaen/itext_summit_pdf_templates
In the above GITHUB example, the rows were prepopulated in the PDF template, I want something like the below screenshot, similar to how Handlebars provide, where a for loop on a hbs template, and I can inject data.

Example:
Suppose I have a table like below
[image]

But here the row count is dynamic based on data set, how to scale the table dynamically

Note:
I cant create the template in HTML, like handlebars, etc...
Since business people with little to no technical background will be the users who will be generating the PDF template.

Comment: Hi, check out iText DITO templating solution which looks like the right product for your needs: https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-dito

Comment: Thanks @AlexeySubach
I did took a look at that DITO, but I wanted something where I can provide the template to iText and it creates the Document for us, is that feature available in iText

Comment: Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can search the all key values of your JSON, and before insert this value in PdFTable. In my case, i get the lastCellNum:

Row row = rowIterator.next();

```
          PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(row.getLastCellNum());
          Iterator<Cell> cellRow = row.iterator();
          
          while(cellRow.hasNext()) {
          Cell cell = cellRow.next();
```